# stock: Calculating sell based on price

Tags: algebra-precalculus, algorithms

I'm interested in being a scalp trader and I made my own math app that can determine the profit based on the buying price per share, selling price per share, and number of shares.

For greater certainty, shares is one number which represents the number of shares in the sell order and the number of shares in the buy order. For example, If I use 100 as the shares value, then it means a buy order of 100 shares, and a sell order of 100 shares.

User inputs are...

```
BuyPrice
SellPrice
Shares
```

Backend equation to calculate profit is as follows...

```
BuyCost = Shares * BuyPrice
SellCost = Shares * SellPrice
Commission = (BuyCost + SellCost) * 0.01
SecFee = (BuyCost + SellCost) * 0.00001
FinraFee = Shares * 0.00000123
TotalFees = Commission + SecFee + FinraFee
Profit = SellCost - BuyCost - TotalFees
```

How do I rearrange the math so that I use Profit as the input and have the stock selling price per share returned to me as an output?

**Edit-1:**
The above equations assume "selling price per share", "BuyPrice" and number "Shares" are known and the shown algorithm, when followed in sequence (executed) produces the value for the "profit". What the OP is after is, to find the equation(s)/Algorithm that would provide a value for the "selling price per share" given the value of the "profit".

The requirement requires knowledge of Algbebra.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Suggestion to readers: Enough down-voting.

Answer (score 2):

Hint:
For ease of writing, I have re-written your code as a set of equations as follows:

```
K1=0.01
K2=0.00001
K3=0.00000123
BC = NS * BP 

SellCost = NS * x

Commission = (BC + [(NS * x)]) * K1

SecFee = (BC + [(NS * x)]) * K2

FF = NS * K3

TF= Commission + SecFee + FF

Profit = [(NS * x)] - BC – TF
```

You need to ensure that you use the appropriate data types in your code and check to prevent dividing by zero.

In the above, you are after the stock selling price per share (the selling price for all shares is named "$x$" in the above code). All other variables are either given or can be calculated.

Using the last line, we can turn the equation in a relation in the variable "$x$" and when it is zero, we can solve for "$x$".

The following step keeps expanding the variables that require operations so that we get $1$ line with "$x$" as the single variable.

```
(NS * x) - BC - Profit - TF = 0

(NS * x) - BC - Profit - ((Commission) + (SecFee) + FF)) = 0

(NS * x) - BC - Profit - (((BC) + [(NS * x)]) * K1) + (SecFee) + FF)) = 0

(NS * x) - BC - Profit - ((( NS * BP ) + [(NS * x)]) * K1) + ((( NS * BP ) + [(NS * x)]) * K2) + FF)) = 0
```

If you expand the last line using simple Algebra, you will get a relation in the form:

$$A_1x^{n}+A_2x^{n-1}+\ldots+A_n=0$$

Once you get this equation, you can solve for the variable "$x$".

You will still need to divide the value of "$x$" by NS (Shares) to get the stock selling price per share.

Your code then, could consist of only that one line.

Note: I have not verified the accuracy or precision of the above approach but I hope that you at least get the point.

Comment: nice answer     .........+1

Comment: @ShivaVenkata, thank you.